# symfony command shell execution retun 0 after making cron

Tags: shell, symfony, cron, command, exec

When I run:

```
shell_exec(ps -ef | grep '/pathtobin/bin/console app:import_process 1 60' | wc -l)
```

in symfony command it return correct count. But after making it as cron like:

```
* * * * * php /pathtobin/contact/bin/console app:import_process
```

this the same code return 0 if more than one process exist .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to grep and run two different commands. It must work when you removed the command parameters from the grep sentence if they are specifically not important for you.

grep:

```
ps -ef | grep '/pathtobin/bin/console app:import_process 1 60'
```

crontab:

```
* * * * * php /pathtobin/contact/bin/console app:import_process
```

Comment: sorry it my question mistake.i run both command ps -ef | grep '/pathtobin/bin/console app:import_process' and ps -ef | grep '/pathtobin/bin/console app:import_process 1 60' .but return zero in 2 cases

Comment: No problem. Do you create the crontab entry with the user which you use calling the command by hand? Otherwise, the command has might be finalized instantly with an error because the application would not be able to write some necessary files like log, cache etc.